# rails if statement, if no records found

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

I'm trying to create an if statement so that if there are no records found, a default message is displayed. I currently have this:

```
- if @n == nil || @n ==""
  welcome
- else
  - @n.each do |n|      
    = n.name
    = raw " - "
    = n.company
```

but it ignores the first line and just shows the record when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to query the instance variable for blank? :

```
- if @n.blank?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    - if @n.blank?
      welcome
    - else
      - @n.each do |n|      
        = n.name
        = raw " - "
        = n.company
```

Answer (score 0):

If in a method

```
if @object.blank?
 #whatever you want to happen
else
 #whatever you want to happen
```

If in a block

```
<% if @object.blank? %><%= #foo %>
<% else %>
<%= #bar %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the empty string `""` evaluates as truthy, which is the opposite of what the OP desires

Comment: thanks, so the blank method would work better here, have edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think @n is supposed to be an array of objects, not a string, so you should rather check if it's empty:

```
if @n == nil || @n == []
```

If you're using rails (& therefore activesupport) the .blank? (suggested by others) works for all those cases

```
nil.blank? #=> true
"".blank? #=> true
[].blank? #=> true
```